# Simple Search Form Tag over SSL

Tags: search, ssl

The simple search form tag is breaking SSL. How do I go about making the simple search form tag secure over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't change site URL in config... that fixed it.

Comment: Can you edit your answer so that your fix is more clear? The above doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the above answer, you need to update the "site_url" variable that is hard-wired in /system/expressionengine/config/config.php. And if using MSM, in the index.php file of the secondary domain.

Change the URL to begin with either "https://", or simply "//" if you have your site otherwise set up to load either over http or https.